# How to avoid printing (null)?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print these tokens but I keep printing (null) at the end. This is the null pointer but I thought I accounted for this in the while loop. 
Edit: Oh, I'm not trying to print the first string in input. I'm trying to print everything after the first input but I keep printing that (null)

```
input = strtok(input_buffer, "\n ")
while (input != NULL)
{
   input = strtok(NULL, "\n");
   printf("%s", input);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: The `while` condition is only checked at the start of each loop iteration. The loop doesn't magically exit if `input` changes halfway through the loop.

Comment: It seems like the question has been answered multiply, but it is not marked as solved. Click the tick on the best answer so it becomes green!

Answer (score 2):

Switch the order of the printf/strtok in the loop, since you already have the first token from outside the loop

```
input = strtok(input_buffer, "\n ")
while (input != NULL)
{
    printf("%s", input);
    input = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the order of things a bit.

```
input = strtok(input_buffer, "\n ")
while (input != NULL)
{
    // Print first.
    printf("%s", input);
    input = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a for loop:

```
for(input = strtok(input_buffer, "\n ");input != NULL;input = strtok(NULL, "\n"))
{
    // Print first.
    printf("%s", input);
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are first assigning values to variable **input** and then printing it.Remember, you are changing the value of **input** inside while loop.Just interchange 4th and 5th line. Try this:

```
input = strtok(input_buffer, "\n ")
while (input != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%s", input);
                    input = strtok(NULL, "\n");
                }
                printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

After separating a string your printing the string, so the previous string will be lose , so print the string before separate on next time.

```
    input = strtok(input_buffer, "\n  ");
    while (input != NULL)
   {
   printf("%s", input);
   input = strtok(NULL, "\n");

  }
   printf("\n");
```